# How to decide multiprocessing limit in Python?

Tags: python, python-multiprocessing

How does the multiprocess limit work in different core systems? Suppose a 4-core CPU divides a process in 4, but if I give multiprocess limit 60, I can see in Task Manager or by `top` command that 60 process are created, will limit 4 and limit 60 differ in a 4-core CPU PC?

In my PC where `multiprocessing.cpu_count()` is 8, the max limit I can put here is 61 and it is taking around 6 min for 10k data to process.

Now on a server where `multiprocessing.cpu_count()` is 16, I am able to put limit to 200, but the time it takes is the same 6 min. How to decide  or calculate max multiprocessing limit, and how it will work?

On My laptop:

```
    multiprocessing.cpu_count() : 8
    pool = Pool(61)
    pool.map(API_Call, data_arg) #where data_arg contains 10K json data to upload from API
    pool.close()
    pool.join()`
time taken : 6min
```

On the server:

```
    multiprocessing.cpu_count() : 200
    pool = Pool(61)
    pool.map(API_Call, data_arg)
    pool.close()
    pool.join()
time taken : 6min
```

Comment: each process is allocated to a core.  where is the code or [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) ?

Comment: Allocating a pool size that's significantly larger than the number of available cores is not a good idea. You'll just cause contention. Try creating the Pool without any argument(s) and let the underlying implementation take care of the actual pool size. That also makes the code more portable. Also, if the subprocesses are mainly concerned with acquiring data from an API (over the internet?) then multithreading might be more appropriate

Answer (score 1):

First things first:
if you are seeing the same time for finishing all tasks on two different systems, with a different core count, and different network capabiities, you are likely being throttled - or otherwise being limited - on the I/O side.  The naming of the function you are calling suggests you are calling a foreign API - they are limiting you (or been themselves on their limit as you flood-call the API).

Second: there does not seen to be a hard-limit on how many process you can open, either manually or by calling `multiprocessing.Pool`, but each process running Python will take a considerable amount of system resources, like memory and open-files for internal pipes, library files, etc... - these could be tuned at the operating system level if needed.

But the real fact is that multi-processing is nice for allowing Python to freely use different system cores, without the GIL, which limits ay porcess running Python to a single concurrent thread running Python code - so, for CPU intensive tasks, it makes sense to open as many processes as you have CPU cores - maybe up to a couple extra ones just to ensure that if some of them get data-starved, the others can run at full-pace.

If your workload is a mix of CPU intensive and data-limited APIs it makes sense to either create mixed workers: sub-process that will themselves create thread-pools, or better yet, use async-io so they can fetch/flush all dara they need, while keeping one worker thread doing the heavy CPU lift - or heterogenous workers: some that will do the lagging I/O, and other, fewer workers, that will do the CPU part (that could be a nice architecture to enable horizontal scaling).

TLDR; your process pool won't perform any better than CPU_count + ~2, for any CPU-bound task, and for I/O bound tasks, using multi-threading is more efficient anyway.

Comment: Thank you for your input, In function we are parsing the into json format, and as api has limit for taking one data per api call. So we used multiprocessing, it reduce time by 3 time. but I thought system with more core cpu reduce time more.

Comment: Also I am trying exception handling inside multiprocess function for API calls, so is there any document how to handle error in multiprocess because, if any one process throws a error whole program terminates.